# Capybara ajax request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec, capybara

I am using capybara for testing behavior of my application. There is some js code on page, which executes on page load. It sends ajax request to server. I want to test parameters of that request, how i can access them?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript and get result using `page.evaluate_script` method. If you store the parameter values in any variable you can access it.

Example:

```
result = page.evaluate_script('4 + 4');
```

Refer: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#scripting

Comment: I need to access parameters included in ajax request, not stored somewhere. I need to access last_request object or something else...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can test this in one shot. You can use page_evaluate in your tests to store the value in a variable, but this only works for simple requests. As Siddick pointed out above you could store the value of your ajax call in a variable:

```
result = page.evaluate_script("response_of_your_ajax_call")
```

Simply replace response_of_your_ajax_call with your actual ajax. This isn't integration testing though- it's much closer to unit testing your js. If you're going to write the test this way then I would recommend also writing a test that simulates what an end user would do to trigger the ajax request (clicking a link, button, etc.).